# Being sensitive vs To be sensitive

Tags: verbs, gerund-vs-infinitive

Being sensitive to others when taking part in a general discussion is a useful quality to have.

vs

To be sensitive to others when taking part in a general discussion is a useful quality to have.

I know that the first phrase is correct. But why? Can you explain to me?

Comment: It's a gerund so it's being used as a noun